# Prisma can't finding any environmental variables when Nuxt is in production

Tags: prisma, nuxtjs3

When the Nuxt is in dev, Prisma works perfectly. However when I am in production I get the error below from prisma. I have tried running `npx prisma generate` before and after building, moving the .env file to both the prisma and the .prisma directory but I still get the same error. I have created a repo where I recreated the problem [repo](https://github.com/jeky1950/nuxt-prisma). Thank you in advance.

```
Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:


error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:10
   |
 9 |   provider = "sqlite"
10 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   |

Validation Error Count: 1
  at Rn.handleRequestError (C:\Users\petal\Desktop\Work\nuxt-prisma\.output\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:174:7601)
  at Rn.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\petal\Desktop\Work\nuxt-prisma\.output\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:174:6754)
  at C:\Users\petal\Desktop\Work\nuxt-prisma\.output\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:177:3010
  at async C:\Users\petal\Desktop\Work\nuxt-prisma\.output\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:177:3225
  at async t._executeRequest (C:\Users\petal\Desktop\Work\nuxt-prisma\.output\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:177:11403)
  at async /C:/Users/petal/Desktop/Work/nuxt-prisma/.output/server/chunks/data.get.mjs:6:16
  at async Object.handler (/C:/Users/petal/Desktop/Work/nuxt-prisma/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1285:19)
  at async toNodeHandle (/C:/Users/petal/Desktop/Work/nuxt-prisma/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1360:7)
  at async ufetch (/C:/Users/petal/Desktop/Work/nuxt-prisma/.output/server/node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)
  at async $fetchRaw2 (/C:/Users/petal/Desktop/Work/nuxt-prisma/.output/server/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.d438bb6f.mjs:206:26)
```

Comment: a .env file is not for production. Set the environment variable on the host machine in production.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHamilton, thank you for your response. However it should still be able to be read in production according to the nuxt docs https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env

Comment: From your link: "However, after your server is built, you are responsible for setting environment variables when you run the server. Your .env file will not be read at this point. How you do this is different for every environment..."

Comment: Ok. So tools do you suggest I use to test whether the build can actually see the Env Variable without actually deploying it to a server

Comment: You can set environment variables on your local machine, just google how to for your operating system. They are just key value pairs like the .env file. If you're confused why this is necessary, it's because these are generally secrets that should never be pushed to a repo.

Comment: Let me do that @ChrisHamilton. Thank you.